# Running a CURL command in Zapier

Tags: curl, zapier

How can I get this CURL command to run on a schedule in Zapier?

curl --request POST \   --url https://auth-integration.servicetitan.io/connect/token \   --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \   --data grant_type=client_credentials \   --data client_id=c{client_id}\   --data client_secret={client_secret} \

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `Webhook by Zapier` as an action (and Schedule by Zapier as a trigger):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can create a custom Zapier UI app to implement custom URLS. https://platform.zapier.com/

Also, I recently learnt you can do this by making a custom request with the zapier webhook App.
https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations/webhook/60510/send-custom-webhook-requests-with-new-recieved-webhooks

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUri8.png]

Comment: This is not correct- you can run custom urls using `Webhook by Zapier`. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks , just found out about that and I have edited my answer.